sass version installed and npm start giving stylesheet error message
I have package.json which is working till this morning and it stopped working all of the sudden and considering all inputs from stackoverflow,I fixed that issue using "export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider" command. But later for all the dependency and module descripency issues, I used npm add <module_name> --legacy-peer-deps command and that resolved the npm install issues.
But after the successful installtion of  node-modules, npm run start is giving issues related to sass module.I was using node-sass module before these issues came up. But now I am forced to install sass module. I installed sass module, now again I am facing issues while running the application. Please help me with your suggestions. I am using node@18.20.0 and npm@10.7.0
Here I am attaching my package.json and also the error message I am acing. Let me know if you need more details to understand the scenario.
{
  "name": "code",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/helper-builder-react-jsx": "^7.12.13",
    "@mdi/js": "^5.8.55",
    "@mdi/react": "^1.4.0",
    "@size-limit/file": "^4.10.2",
    "@size-limit/time": "^4.10.2",
    "@testing-library/dom": "^10.4.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "6.4.8",
    "@testing-library/react": "16.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "14.5.2",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.36",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/qs": "^6.9.5",
    "@types/query-string": "^6.3.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.53",
    "@types/react-datepicker": "^6.2.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
    "@types/react-google-recaptcha": "^2.1.9",
    "@types/react-html5-camera-photo": "^1.5.0",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.11",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.6",
    "@types/react-router-redux": "^5.0.27",
    "@types/react-transition-group": "^4.4.0",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.5",
    "animate.css": "^4.1.1",
    "archiver": "^5.3.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "child_process": "^1.0.2",
    "connected-react-router": "^6.9.3",
    "crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
    "firebase": "^8.0.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "js-file-download": "^0.4.12",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "jspdf": "^2.3.1",
    "localforage": "^1.10.0",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "qs": "^6.9.4",
    "query-string": "^6.13.7",
    "react": "17.0",
    "react-date-picker": "^11.0.0",
    "react-datepicker": "^4.10.0",
    "react-device-detect": "^1.17.0",
    "react-dom": "17.0",
    "react-google-recaptcha": "^3.1.0",
    "react-html5-camera-photo": "^1.5.4",
    "react-icons": "^5.2.0",
    "react-indexed-db": "^1.0.12",
    "react-native": "^0.74.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.19.11",
    "react-redux": "9.1.2",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom-v5-compat": "^6.26.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "react-swipeable": "^6.0.1",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.4.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "redux-first-history": "^5.2.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "sass": "^1.53.0",
    "semantic-ui-css": "^2.4.1",
    "size-limit": "^4.10.2",
    "ssa": "^0.1.27",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1",
    "typescript": "4.6.3",
    "web-vitals": "0.2.4",
    "workbox-background-sync": "^5.1.3",
    "workbox-broadcast-update": "^5.1.3",
    "workbox-cacheable-response": "^5.1.3",
    "workbox-core": "^5.1.3",
    "workbox-expiration": "^5.1.3",
    "workbox-google-analytics": "^5.1.3",
    "workbox-navigation-preload": "^5.1.3",
    "workbox-precaching": "^5.1.3",
    "workbox-range-requests": "^5.1.3",
    "workbox-routing": "^5.1.3",
    "workbox-strategies": "^5.1.3",
    "workbox-streams": "^5.1.3",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "node -e require('./build').build(process.argv)",
    "build:react": "react-scripts build",
    "size": "npm run build && size-limit",
    "start": "react-scripts start"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/crypto-js": "^4.0.1"
  }
}

Error message
./node_modules/semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-oneOf-6-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-4!./node_modules/semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css)
SassError: expected "{".

